# How to check stationarity in panel data with R?

Tags: r, time-series, panel-data

I have panel data (country, year) and would like to check stationarity. To be honest, I am quite unsure how to do this as I am not very familiar with panel data methods. Since I am interested to test if there is a time trend, can I just run the following code using the dependent variable as an object or do I have to first calculate the mean of the dependent variable for each year separately and only then run the code as described below?

```
#Augmented Dickey–Fuller (ADF) t-statistic test for unit root, a series with a trend line will have a unit root and result in a large p-value 
adf.test(Y)
```

```
#Kwiatkowski-Phillips-Schmidt-Shin (KPSS) for level or trend stationarity; a low p-value will indicate a signal that is not trend stationary, has a unit root.
kpss.test(Y, null="Trend")
```

I've tried to visualise stationarity using plots in R using the following code. Unfortunately, I got a very messy plot and have no idea why the red lines are depicted all over the plot.

```
#checking stationary visually
pdf(file="Stationary Y.pdf")
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
plot.new()
plot(year, Y,
     type='l',col='red',
     xlab = "time (t)",
     ylab = "Y(t)",
     main = "Stationary signal")
acf(Y,lag.max = length(Y),
    xlab = "lag #", ylab = 'ACF',main=' ')
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Hey! More people will be able to help if you post your data as well!

Comment: If you work with panel data in R, a package that is typically useful is `plm`. For panel unit root tests, it provides various functions: `purtest`, `cipstest`, and `phansi`. The package's vignett has a section dedicated to panel unit root tests: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plm/vignettes/A_plmPackage.html